# A minimum value problem for a convergent series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, inequality

**Problem.**

Given positive real numbers $a>b$. Let $\{x_n\}_{n=0}^{+\infty}$ be a decreasing sequence of positive numbers such that $x_0=1$. If the series
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x_n^a}{x_{n+1}^b}
$$
converges, find the minimum value of
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x_n^a}{x_{n+1}^b}.
$$

**My Approach.**

I have come up with a method similar to "homogenization", which is inspired by the consistency and homogenization of the equation. My method is as follows.

On one hand, let $x_n=\left(\dfrac{b}{a}\right)^{\frac{n}{a-b}}$, then,
$$\  \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x_n^a}{x_{n+1}^b}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{b}{a}\right)^{n-\frac{b}{a-b}}=\dfrac{a^{\frac{a}{a-b}}b^{\frac{b}{b-a}}}{a-b}$$
so if the minimum value of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x_n^a}{x_{n+1}^b}$ exists, it cannot be greater than $\dfrac{a^{\frac{a}{a-b}}b^{\frac{b}{b-a}}}{a-b}$.

On the other hand, since $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x_n^a}{x_{n+1}^b}>\dfrac{x_0^a}{x_1^b}> 1$, we know that the lower bound of all possible values of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x_n^a}{x_{n+1}^b}$ exists and is positive. Let's denote this lower bound as $C$, then
$$ \ C\leq \dfrac{a^{\frac{a}{a-b}}b^{\frac{b}{b-a}}}{a-b}$$

Let's discuss two cases separately.

Case 1. There exists a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=0}^{+\infty}$ that satisfies the given conditions and $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x_n^a}{x_{n+1}^b}=C$. Let $x_1=t>0$, then
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x_n^a}{x_{n+1}^b}=\dfrac{1}{t^b}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x_n^a}{x_{n+1}^b}=\dfrac{1}{t^b}+t^{a-b}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(x_n/t)^a}{(x_{n+1}/t)^b} $$

Let $\ y_n=\dfrac{x_{n+1}}{t}, n\in\mathbb N$, then $y_n$ is decreasing with initial term $1$. Thus,
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(x_n/t)^a}{(x_{n+1}/t)^b}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{y_n^a}{y_{n+1}^b}\geq C $$
which implies,
$$\ C=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x_n^a}{x_{n+1}^b}\geq \dfrac{1}{t^b}+t^{a-b}C\overset{AM-GM}{\geq}\dfrac{a}{a-b}\left[\dfrac{(a-b)C}{b}\right]^\frac{b}{a} $$
this leads to
$$\ C\geq \dfrac{a^{\frac{a}{a-b}}b^{\frac{b}{b-a}}}{a-b}(*).$$

Case 2. There doesn't exist a sequence $\{x_n\}$ that satisfies the given conditions and makes $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x_n^a}{x_{n+1}^b}=C$, The statement (∗) can be proven similarly.

Hence,
$$\ C = \frac{a^{\frac{a}{a-b}}b^{\frac{b}{b-a}}}{a-b}$$

Therefore, the minimum value of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x_n^a}{x_{n+1}^b}$ is $\frac{a^{\frac{a}{a-b}}b^{\frac{b}{b-a}}}{a-b}$.

**My Problem.**

The method seems a bit too clever to me, and I have never seen it before. Is there a more general approach, perhaps using the Holder's inequality or some other technique? If not, are there similar problems where this trick can be applied? Is there a deeper background or underlying theory behind this method? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by [Find the $\lim_{n\to\infty}\text{inf} \left(\frac {x_0^2}{ x_1}+\frac {x_1^2}{ x_2}+\cdots \frac {x_{n-1}^2}{ x_n}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3442364/find-the-lim-n-to-infty-textinf-left-frac-x-02-x-1-frac-x-12-x), where the minimum is determined for the case $a=2$ and $b=1$, we try to find a constant $K > 0$ such that
$$ \tag{$*$}
 \frac{x^a}{y^b} \ge K (x^{a-b} - y^{a-b})
$$
for all $x, y> 0$. If $K$ is such a constant and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x_n^a}{x_{n+1}^b}$ converges then $x_n\to 0$ and
$$
 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x_n^a}{x_{n+1}^b}
\ge K \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\bigl(x_n^{a-b} - x_{n+1}^{a-b} \bigr) = K \,.
$$

Inequality $(*)$ is equivalent to
$$
x^{a-b} y^b \le \frac 1K x^a + y^a
$$
which reminds of [Young's inequality for products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality_for_products). Indeed, with $p=a/(a-b)$ and $q = a/b$ we have
$$
\begin{align}
x^{a-b} y^b &= \left( \frac ba\right)^{b/a} x^{a-b} \cdot \left( \frac ab\right)^{b/a} y^b \\
&\le \frac{a-b}{a} \left( \frac ba\right)^{b/(a-b)} x^a +
\frac ba  \frac ab y^a \\
&= \frac 1K x^a + y^a
\end{align}
$$
with
$$
 K = \frac{a}{a-b} \left( \frac ab\right)^{b/(a-b)}
= \frac{a^{a/(a-b)}}{b^{b/(a-b)}(a-b)} \, .
$$
This proves that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x_n^a}{x_{n+1}^b} \ge \frac{a^{a/(a-b)}}{b^{b/(a-b)}(a-b)}
$$
for all decreasing sequences $(x_n)$ with $x_0 = 1$, and since you already found that equality is attained for the sequence $x_n=\left(\dfrac{b}{a}\right)^{\frac{n}{a-b}}$, this is the desired minimum.